# How to convert '02-3月 -21' to date 21-03-02 00:00:00 psql

Tags: postgresql, kettle, data-integration

How to convert '02-3月 -21' to date 21-03-02 00:00:00? in postgresql or kettle

Comment: Is that Japanese or Chinese? And is that March 21st, 2002 (Y-M-D as used in China and Japan)  or is that March 2nd, 2021 (D-M-Y)?

Comment: Did you try `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: in Chinese, and I can't use to_timestamp() or date()

Comment: [月](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88) is that not Japanese?

Comment: @Luuk It's also Chinese. See [here for China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Asia#Greater_China) and [here for Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Japan). The characters for dates are the same in both Chinese and Japanese. If it interests you, you can read the history of Japanese kanji [here](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2046.html). Short version: "[kanji] are Chinese characters, which were first introduced to Japan in the 5th century."

Comment: OP: Does your date actually contain the space after 月 or is that a typo in the question? And again: is it Y-M-D or D-M-Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple `replace` can do the trick here. Just replace the Chinese character `月` with nothing and format it.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE ('02-3月-21', '月', ''),'DD-MM-YY');
// output: 2021-03-02 00:00:00+00


SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE ('02-3月-21', '月', ''),'DD-MM-YY'), 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
// output: 21-03-02 00:00:00
```